# Set optimality gap for each goal objective in FICO XPRESS

Tags: python, multi-objective-optimization

FICO XPRESS recently released a feature that supports [multi-objective optimization](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/solver/optimizer/HTML/chapter5.html?scroll=multiobj).

While it allows you to define a tolerance per objective (aka how much you can relax the previous objective), I am not sure how to enforce a different optimization gap for each of the objectives. Maybe for the first objective I want to solve it to 1% optimality gap the second objective to 2% and the third one to 0%.

Any idea whether this is possible in the python api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two callback functions offered before and after each optimization.

```
    p = xp.problem
    def beforeobjective(prob, object):
        if prob.attributes.solvedobjs == 0:
            print("will enforce gap to first objective")
            prob.controls.miprelstop = 2e-2
        if prob.attributes.solvedobjs == 1:
            print("will enforce gap to second objective")
            prob.controls.miprelstop = 1e-2
            # From now on (solves 3,4) the gap will be 1e-2
        
    def afterobjective(prob, object):
        print("Completed solve {}".format(prob.attributes.solvedobjs))
    p.addcbbeforeobjective(beforeobjective, None, 0)
    p.addcbafterobjective(afterobjective, None, 0)
    p.optimize()
```